# Test runner left pane closes after the Salesforce application is open

Tags: automation, salesforce, cypress

I am able to open the application but the test runner left pane closes after the salesforce application is open and execution stops without any error report.
The desired application remains open with no execution.
We can see in RED that the browser is handled by automation(Cypress) but there is no Test Runner left pane.

Sample Code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: I am getting the below error in my chrome console,                                         
    DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://static.lightning.force.com/********HTTP error: status code 503, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE